# Webhost ( linux shared ) which has php imap extension enabled and ports not blocked

Tags: looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Ok, so I've had it with godaddy. What I need from you is a recommandation of a web hosting company that has php imap extension enabled and even if it has this extension enabled, the ports won't be blocked (i've run into 1 host with this problem ... i could use php imap function but... connection timed out ). Bassically I want to make use of osTicket and write an app that retreieves emails from google accounts using imap/pop3. I am only askingthis here because I want to be sure that php imap functions are working as it should, not be enabled, but the ports blocked ( which is useless ). 
PS: i don`t want to rent a whole server computer. I just need a standard hosting account ( maybe with cpanel ). Thank you.

Comment: not a programming question, go ask google.

Comment: Belongs in the webmasters SO site. but personally, I've used Rackspace Cloud quite happily for a few years now. It's cheap and scales nicely.

Comment: Dagon, i have asked google and failed... the host had imap, but had blocked ports

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you think about a VPS system. It's a step between a shared host and a dedicated host with the price in the middle. It's a pain to learn how to set them up but once you get over that hurdle, you don't really have to worry about ports being blocked etc.